# Reading specific rows and plotting using Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have an Excel sheet that has a column of image frames. These frames numbers are not uniformly distributed, e.g. frame 1 may have entries from row 1 to 20 and frame 2 from 21 to 25 and so on. I want to read this data from an Excel sheet that has x and y coordinate for each frame and plot these x and y coordinate in a scattered plot using matplotlib. Here's my code, frame numbers are identified as image index.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

df_xlsx = pd.read_excel('X10.xlsx')
temp = df_xlsx['Image index'][0]
i = 0; #number of the row

xList = []
yList = []
dt = df_xlsx.loc[df_xlsx['Image index'] == 19]
xList = np.array(dt['X position'])
yList = np.array(dt['Y position'])
rList = np.array(dt['Diameter'])

figure(figsize=(10.24,7.68), dpi=100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.xlim([0,1024])
plt.ylim([0,768])
plt.scatter(xList, yList, color ='r')
plt.axis('off')
plt.gcf().set_size_inches((10.24,7.68))

for i in range(len(xList)):
    circle1 = plt.Circle((xList[i], yList[i]), rList[i], color='r')
    ax.add_artist(circle1)
plt.tight_layout(pad=0)
plt.savefig('f=19.png',dpi=100)    
plt.show()
```

[Excel sheet example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9rIS.png)

The problem is every time I need to enter the image index and then save the plot. Can this be done in a loop such that the plot is continuously generated as different plots for each frame number (index frames)? This will save me a lot of time, as I have lots of frames and excel sheets. I am new to Python.

Comment: Welcome to SO. some remarks for your code: ``df_xlsx = pd.read_excel('X10.xlsx')`` won't work unless you are working with a very old version of pandas. Better update your pandas to a newer version. By _excel sheet_ do you mean file or an actual sheet (sheet1, sheet2, ...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby` to step over the image index:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel('X10.xlsx')

for idx, group in df.groupby('Image index'):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10.24, 7.68), dpi=100)
    diameter = 1 * group['Diameter']**2
    ax.scatter(group['X position'], group['Y position'], s=diameter)
    ax.set_xlim(0, 1024)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 768)
    ax.axis('off')
    plt.tight_layout(pad=0)
    plt.savefig(f'Image_index_{idx}.png', dpi=100)
```

Some notes on the other changes I made:

- You don't need to cast the DataFrame columns to arrays or lists.
- You can pass a size parameter `s` to `plt.scatter()` to make the circles; you'll just need to scale the numbers to fit your scale. E.g. you could multiply by some factor other than 1. **Note that in `matplotlib` you are specifying the *area* of the marker, not the diameter.**

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help kwinkunks and also for the notes.

Comment: @VAISHAKHTHOLAN No worries, if it helped you plese don't forget to upvote / select as the answer.